# Textfield only integer values

Tags: vue.js, numbers, integer, textfield, vuex

is there a way to, only input integer values in a text field?
I would set the input type to integer, but it isn't supported by vuejs.

```
<v-text-field
          label="Regular"
          type="number"
        ></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use vue internal directive [v-model.number](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)

```
<input v-model.number="age" type="number">
```